# How do you change the ERROR output color of output created by TSLINT?

Tags: powershell

I am using TSLINT in Angular 12 w/ the command `npm run lint`.  The TSLINT errors are difficult for me to read.

***ERROR: 12:3*** variable-name variable name must be in lowerCamelCase,PascalCase of UPPER_CASE

"ERROR: 12:3" is red.  I viewed $host.privatedata and I only see one option that is using Red.  I changed:

`$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor = 'Yellow'`

And the output from TSLINT is still red using the same Powershell session.

How can I make the ERROR output yellow?

### UPDATE 1

Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1682

Comment: It depends on whether `npm` writes directly to the console. When you write `npm run lint 2>&1 | % {"$_"}`, does this remove the color from error messages? If yes, then we can write a simple RegEx-based filter to colorize lines starting with `ERROR:` differently.

Comment: Yes it does!  That turned the output white.

Comment: Which PowerShell version are you using? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()`

Comment: Powershell Version: 5.1.19041.1682

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, why `$host.PrivateData.ErrorForegroundColor` isn't working.

As a workaround you may merge the *stderr* output of `npm` with the *stdout* stream ([`2>&1`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2#powershell-redirection-operators)), filter error messages by testing for the "ERROR:" prefix and colorize them as you like.

```
npm run lint 2>&1 | ForEach-Object { 
    $msg = "$_"
    if( $msg -like 'ERROR:*' ) {
        Write-Host -ForegroundColor Yellow $msg   # Recolorize error message
    }
    else {
        $msg   # Output as-is
    }
}
```

- The `ForEach-Object` script block runs for each line of *stdout* and *stderr*.
- `$msg = "$_"` makes sure that messages from *stderr*, which are actually of type `System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord`, are converted to string.

Comment: If all you need is to remove the red this simplified version zett42 wrote earlier works great: `npm run lint 2>&1 | % {"$_"}`